# Controlling multiple indoor wifi smart switches with a separate outside photocell

Tags: lighting

I have three groups of outdoor house lights and one group of landscape lights.  They're on four separate light switches.  The house light switches are located indoors in separate locations far apart, and the landscape light switch is located outside far from the other three.

A year ago I replaced all four switches with timers to increase their usefulness and convenience.  But it's turning out to be a hassle to adjust all of those timers every few weeks to stay in synch with seasonal daylight changes.

If I replace the three indoor timers/switches with wifi smart switches, can I then replace the outside timer/switch with a photocell device (or install such a device elsewhere) to control all four groups of lights with the single photocell?

Comment: How do you want these lights to actually work? One photoswitch turning on and off all the lights normally, with individual manual overrides for each?

Comment: Yes.  Exactly as you have suggested.

Comment: How many wires are running between the locations now, and is pulling new wire an option?

Comment: Product recommendations and shopping questions are off topic.  That said Visit smarthome.com, Insteon will do what you want with one exception, there is no photocell in the standard Insteon branded products, however with the hub you can program ‘Sunrise’ and ‘Sunset’, which are recalculated daily based on your location.

Comment: Sounds really good.  I'll check it out.  Thank you.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel - Pulling new wire is not an option.  House walls are Insulated Concrete Forms (concrete and rebar), so doing any thing involving outside walls is a big deal.  There are even 3 different breaker panels involved with the 4 switches, too.

Comment: Intermatic makes some in-wall timers that replace the light switches and automatically adjust every day for seasonal sunrise/sunset changes.  This option doesn't give you all the convenience of smart switches (e.g. no master switch), but it could save a bit of money.

Answer (score 1):

As @Tyson mentioned in his comment, you can do this with most smart switches as long as you have a hub to set everything up. Most smart switches nowadays operate on several protocols (Z-wave, Zigbee, etc) and many hubs handle multiple protocols as well, but just make sure your switch and hub both use the same protocol.

In the setup of the switches, just program them to come on at sunset and off at sunrise, which will be calculated based on your location.

Alternatively, if you don't want to use smart switches, you can get semi-smart timer switches that will automatically adjust, based on your latitude, for sunrise and sunset. I've used [this one](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004AP92N2) in the past and it's worked great, although there are others on the market as well.